# how to create multi user paramerter in zabbix from a script

Tags: bash, zabbix

This is a shell script return 2 values one for packet loss percentage and another for True or False :

```
SERVER_IP=$1

checkip=`ping -c 2 -W 2 $SERVER_IP | grep "packet loss" | cut -d " " -f 6  | cut -d "%" -f1`
test1=$? 
echo $checkip 
if [ $test1 -eq 0 ]; then

 echo "1"

else

 echo "0"

fi
```

in zabbix when you create an item  you enter only one parameter with value but i have 2 values one packet loss and second for ping result (0 and 1)

how can i create two items 1 for packet lost percentage and second for ping health check with only this script? i dont want to create another one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [Andre](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5512607/andr%C3%A9-d%C3%A9o)

try this script this will guide you to what exactly you want :

```
#!/bin/bash

    case $1 in

    packetloss) ping -c2 -W1 -q 8.8.8.8 | grep -oP '\d+(?=% packet loss)' ;;
    timeout) ping -c2 -q 8.8.8.8 | grep 'time' | awk -F',' '{ print$4}' | awk '{print $2}' | cut -c 1-4 ;;
    *) echo "Use: packetloss , timeout";;

    esac
```

try (im in zsh):

```
zabbix_agentd -t ping.loss\[timeout\]   
ping.loss[timeout]                            [t|1000]
```

or in zabbix server use get ( im also in zsh here too):

```
zabbix_get -s 172.20.4.49 -k ping.loss\[timeout\]         
1001
```

now create items with these keys.

Answer (score 0):

UserParameter=key[*],/path_of_script.sh $1

At the GUI:
Key: key[Server_IP]

Another example:
UserParameter=general[*],/usr/local/etc/scripts/general.sh $1 $2 $3 $4 $5 $6 $7 $8 $9

$ cat general.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

case $1 in

ddate) ddate;;
minute) echo "`date +%M`%2" | bc;;
files) ls -l $2 | grep ^- | wc -l;;
size.dir) du -s $2 | cut -f1;;
script) /bin/bash /usr/local/etc/scripts/script.sh;;
*) echo "Use: ddate, minute, files <parameters>, size.dir <parameters> or script";;

esac
```

$ zabbix_get -s Server_IP -k general[minute]

Comment: hi , tank you for ansewr ,  i change my script to                #!/bin/bash
# Ping
# Ping scripts for Zabbix monitor. Conditional return
# of 1=success | 0=failed

SERVER_IP=$1
checkip=`ping -c 2 -W 2 $SERVER_IP | grep "packet loss" | cut -d " " -f 6  | cut -d "%" -f1`
#test1=$?
echo $checkip 
if [ $checkip -eq 0 ]; then

 result="1"
 echo $alive

else

 loss="0"
 echo $loss

fi
now how i can to create userparamater for loss and alive and check ip ?